# Configuring Home Page Address

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess, rel-canonical

I though this was a simple issue. When i type in the browser:

`www.example.com`

it changes to:

`www.example.com/home/`

This delivers the proper contents from the `Home` page, but i wish to stay showing the `www.example.com` address.

I've configured `%postnames%` as *Permalink*, and setting the *Static Front Page* as the page `Home` through the *Customizer*. Also, i've deleted the `.htaccess` both on the `public_html` and the `wp` folder. The page has the title `Home` with the slug word `home`. AFAIK no other redirects remain on server side.

On *Settings/General Settings/WordPress Address (URL)*:
`http://www.example.com/wp`

On *Settings/General Settings/Site Address (URL)*:
`http://www.example.com`

I dont see any redirects on server side...

What should i do to make this "blind" redirection without affecting the address?. I need to remove the duplicate `www.example.com/myhome` and `www.example.com` for *JSON Canonical URL* purposes.

Comment: Have you installed WordPress in a sub folder named myhome?

Comment: This is installed under `public_html/wp` folder :/

Comment: Why can't you migrate it to your public_html root directory?

Comment: I already did it. I will auto answer my question :/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no clear evidence of any present redirect from the following sources:

1. The `htaccess`, both under the `public_html` and under the `public_html/folder` (where `folder` is the directory having all the wp files), removing and regenerating them by mean of updating the `permalinks`,
2. The `.htaccess` files were at some point deleted, and regenerated,
3. The domain server, removing all possible redirects,
4. The `index.php` files, which redirects calls where there are no files to serve,
5. The `Static Page` is correctly configurated,

The options you have are:

1. To *Create* a *dumb* home page `index.php`,`home.php` or any similar flavoured choice, on the `public_html` folder,
2. To seek for a *plugin* able to do that (Of course i skipped these step, in order not to increase even more the huge amount of manhours for solving this issue),
3. To *migrate/reinstall* everything on the `public-html` folder.

The last choice, is by far the simpler and straighter.

By default, a fresh installation of WP leaves everything well configured on the `www.example.com` folder. IF you install on a `wp` or a `folder`, you lost the pretty address, and risk a *little uglier* canonical url (`www.example.com/home`).

Check here, https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress-, in particular, the section "If You Have Accidentally Changed your WordPress Site URL" which shows two 'hack' lines to reenter the modified folder.

Thus, when WP install to the same 'public_html', the `Canonical URL` can then preserved to `www.example.com`, and no duplicity is found.

For clarity the steps are:

- Rename `folder` to `newfolder`, where `folder` is the directory for the WP installation,
- Edit the `index.php` and `.htaccess` and change 'folder' with 'newfolder', if required,
- Add the two lines on `wp-login.php` (see the above guide!):

  `update_option('siteurl', 'http://www.example.com/newfolder' );`
  `update_option('home', 'http://www.example.com/newfolder' );`
- Open `http://www.example.com/newfolder/wp-admin`. The update should be ready now.

And that's all. The migrated WP installation now starts directly at `www.example.com` after the proper configuration of the `Static Page`.

Comment: And remove the update_option code after reloading your site.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option to mention your site address in General Settings. I think that is what you need to change.

Comment: Hello,

On `Settings/General Settings/WordPress Address (URL)`:
`http://www.example.com/wp`

On `Settings/General Settings/Site Address (URL)`:
`http://www.example.com`

I dont see any other options. Nor on server side...